# Adding strongback bracing to an existing floor truss

Tags: framing, floor, support, truss

I just bought a house built around 2006. The floor has a ~32' span supported by 24" deep trusses on 19.2" centers. The trusses do not have strongback bracing installed (well there is a 2x4 nailed face down into the bottom chord, but that doesn't count). As a result there is some bounce when you go across it at a brisk walk. I plan to install 2 strongbacks at ~10' spacing. *My question is how can I get the strongbacks into place?* I have had a couple of thoughts but am unsure which one will provide the best performance. Trusses are a standard 24" truss web with no HVAC openings

1. Remove some siding and cut a hole in the rimboard and run the longest 2x6s I can get, and affix them to the verticals. Patch and seal the rimboard, patch and seal the wrap, replace siding and done.
2. Run ~6' ~2x6 sections up into the truss from the inside, lap them between trusses on the inside with a 19.2" 2x6, then run long (8' probably) 6" sections of more flexible OSB along the other side of the vertical to reinforce the connection (?) screwing it into the laps and the verticals.

Anyone dealt with this situation and have any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Is there a square opening in the center of the joists where you can attach strongback to bottom chord and  upright 2x?

Comment: no, no HVAC openings / square openings.

Answer (score 1):

I've built quite a few homes with floor trusses, and we didn't always have the foresight or opportunity to lay in strongbacks during the truss set. Have you tried getting longer 2x6 boards in there? You might be surprised how much they flex. I'd bet you can get 16-footers in there without much issue.

I'd start with that. Just don't let your grip slip and smack yourself in the chin. Once you have one in place, use it up against the top chords as a slider for the next ones.

Otherwise, you're onto something with the OSB. As you probably know, OSB is what makes up the vertical component of TJI joists, meaning it has plenty of strength on that axis to act as a strongback. You could rip 8-10" widths from 1/2"x8' sheets, flex them into place, and stagger the butt joints of two layers by two trusses. I have confidence that this would do at least as well as 2x6 lumber.

Actually, 7/16"x10' OSB is commonly available. If you shortened them to 115.2" you'd span one more joist.

FYI, such strongbacks are usually set against the top chord. By keeping them tight in all cases you ensure a flat floor. (Even engineered trusses can have some crown or wiggle to them.) If you have the option I'd move your ducts down and do that. It might help to have them temporarily out of the way anyway. Otherwise it probably doesn't matter much at this point.

Comment: No way a 16 footer will flex enough to slip into place from below .

Comment: I'd put real money on it being not only possible, but fairly easy in that long run. You can start them in the adjacent opening.

Comment: My gut agrees with Kris, but I look at it this way: I need to buy a long 2x6. If isherwood is right and I can get it to work without cutting a hole in the side of the house great. If not, I have a 2x6 I need anyway. So, no harm in trying.

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if strongbacks will stiffen the trusses to take any vibration out.

The subfloor is probably not thick enough so if flexes and vibrates when you walk across it quickly. Do you know the thickness? I see the contractor laid the subfloor with the grade stamp up.

If you find a grade stamp, there are two numbers imprinted with a “slash” between them. The first number is the span rating for roof sheathing and the second is for floor spans. I’ll bet they used 5/8” thick plywood and not 3/4”.

You can add 10 strongbacks and it won’t matter. You’re just adding “Dead Load”.

Comment: I don't interpret "bounce" as vibration, but as flex under weight.

Comment: Thickness is 3/4" (have some exposed subfloor in the basement stairwell) and the flooring is 5/8 oak plank. I can find plenty of grade stamps, problem is none of them are fully legible - machine looks like it was missing or out of ink on most of them.

Comment: Is the oak flooring on underlayment or just the subfloor?

Comment: If you look close, you’ll see some of the plywood is installed in the wrong direction. It doesn’t work that way.

Comment: You probably have a net effective thickness of 1/2”.

Comment: @isherwood Why isn’t that “bounce” reflected as “vibration” when the op says it occurs “when you walk across it at a brisk walk” ?

Comment: I thought part of the problem with this type of construction is that it is "light" compared to comparable 2x10, 2x12, construction.  It just doesn't have the mass, and so it is easier to cause/set up vibrations by normal activities like walking.  I was told this by the builder of my previous house that used engineered I-joists for the floor joists, and we complained about the same thing.

Comment: @SteveSh Not true. If the framing is designed properly, it has the same deflection, vibration, etc. as any other type of construction. The trouble comes from truss manufacturers design to the “nats eyelash” or designs to a weaker standard...like l/180 instead of l/360 deflection. It won’t fall do, but you’ll feel the bounce (vibration). Often the truss manufacturer is bidding against a stick frame system so they cut the standards to earn the bid.

Comment: Mostly it's because spans are so much greater. You wouldn't have a 32' span with solid lumber, or even 20'. Those trusses weigh more per foot than a 2x12.

Comment: @Lee Sam  - What you say about the amount of allowed deflection is true, but I don't think the same can be said about vibration.  First of all, the tendency of a structure to vibrate or support vibration is a function of it's mass and how stiff it is.  The lighter the structure and the stiffer it is, the higher it's natural vibration.  Second, I do not think truss manufacturers have a vibration standard or a natural frequency resonance goal they have to meet.  If there is one, I haven't come across it.

Comment: @SteveSh So you don’t think defection has anything to do with vibration? You say “the tendency of a structure to vibrate...is a function of its mass and how stiff it is”. That’s true for the building not for the component within the building.

Comment: @Lee Sam - Not true.  What I said applies to any object, irrespective of it's size or mass or composition.  The only difference is to what degree it deflects; or at what frequency it vibrates (its resonance).  True for a marble, a baseball, a baseball bat, a car, a building, or a rocket.

Comment: @LeeSam where is there plywood run wrong direction?

Comment: @Kris The top of the picture shows the grain on the plywood running parallel to trusses.

Comment: -1 because strong backs are in fact important to the truss floor joist system.

Comment: @Kris You’re confusing “bracing” with “strongbacks”. Bracing keeps the trusses perfectly vertical so they don’t layover on their side when fully loaded AND are critical to the installation. (The op has already said the bracing is in place and laying flat on the bottom chord.) Strongbacks are a member that helps transfer loads from structural member to adjacent structural members.

Comment: I’m not confused

Comment: @Kris Try this: https://youtu.be/P00Uv440n-U

Comment: https://www.jlconline.com/how-to/framing/bracing-floor-trusses_o